# SP2010 Profile properties

Tags: user-profile, web-part

Can the "EditProperties" page be edited? The URL points to a /layouts so I am assuming that it must be done outside Sharepoint Designer (I could not find it in Designer even as System account).  I would like to make changes affecting one of the web zones and web-part placement.  I am also wondering if I modify it, will this cause a problem with one of the profile databases.

THanks James..I left this in a comment (sorry)..here is a URL (with server name removed):

http://servername:port/_layouts/EditProperty.aspx?Name=AccountName&IsSection=False&ProfileType=User&ApplicationID=b1980ae2%2Df6f9%2D44f1%2Db1c8%2Dad53f75e332b

Comment: I would not recommend editing this file. Updates and patches will certainly overwrite your changes.

Answer (score 1):

This file will live in the 14 Hive / SharePoint root folder, and I doubt that editing this page is a supported customisation of SharePoint (unless it can be ghosted).

Just to clarify, what is the full URL of the page you wish to edit?

Comment: Thanks James for your prompt response--appreciate it!  I am looking for the .aspx page that takes a property as an arguement.  For example, take the the URL of form:

http://server_name:port/_layouts/EditProperty.aspx?Name=AccountName&IsSection=False&ProfileType=User&ApplicationID=b1980ae2%2Df6f9%2D44f1%2Db1c8%2Dad53f75e332b

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to happen to the UserProfile in the edit page.  The page renders the fields as specified in the User Profile Service Applicaiton.  If you want more fields you should add them from the management console for the User Profile Service Applicaiton in Central Admin.  If you wish to hide some fileds that can be done as well.